# coldfusion scheduled tasks iis permission

Tags: iis, coldfusion, permissions, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to use the ColdFusion administrator to schedule a task.  It is returning an error which says that there are not enough permissions to execute the task.

I can successfully execute the cfm file in IE, so it's not an error with the actual file.

So from what I've read about this, it appears to be an IIS problem.  Do I need to change IIS_WPG permissions on the scheduled tasks folder?

I'm wondering what permissions I need to change to be able to execute scheduled tasks.  Also would be interested in best security practices.

Comment: Is there any security -- basic authentication, etc. -- on the URL you are trying to call?

Comment: no basic authentication, no username/password, no https

Comment: Can you CFHTTP to the target page?  What do you see when you dump the attempt?

Comment: just tried, I get a 401 error "HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to server configuration"  tried localhost, full domain name, and 127.0.0.1

Comment: When you are viewing the target page in IE, are you viewing it from the server, or from a client?  What happens if you view it from the server using a browser?

Comment: i did this all from the server's browser first.  the client browser also did not work.

Comment: Can you CFHTTP anywhere else?  Is there a local firewall or similar?  And if a client browser can't reach the page, why can a local browser see it?

Comment: neither client browser nor local browser is able to execute cfhttp.  both client browser and local browser can view all other pages in the web application.  i have not been able to excecute cfhttp anywhere.  i don't think there's a local firewall.  the error message said something about IIS.

Comment: try creating a folder inside inetpub\wwwroot\ call it test, then try to call it using localhost/test/myscript.cfm I am asuming its a Windows Box. make sure in IIS you have execute and script permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I was not initially aware of this, I found out that windows integrated authentication was turned on.

I had the server admin set the IIS security on folder to anonymous access which contained the tasks.  This fixed the problem.